# Add Fade Transition to older Unslider script?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a simple way to add a fade transition to this script?  Based on the manner of it shuffling the items from left to right I didn't think it was possible.  May just use another script but figured it didn't hurt to get a second opinion.

```
(function(e, t) {
if (!e) return t;
var n = function() {
    this.el = t;
    this.items = t;
    this.sizes = [];
    this.max = [0, 0];
    this.current = 0;
    this.interval = t;
    this.opts = {
        speed: 500,
        delay: 3e3,
        complete: t,
        keys: !t,
        dots: t,
        fluid: t
    };
    var n = this;
    this.init = function(t, n) {
        this.el = t;
        this.ul = t.children("ul");
        this.max = [t.outerWidth(), t.outerHeight()];
        this.items = this.ul.children("li").each(this.calculate);
        this.opts = e.extend(this.opts, n);
        this.setup();
        return this
    };
    this.calculate = function(t) {
        var r = e(this),
            i = r.outerWidth(),
            s = r.outerHeight();
        n.sizes[t] = [i, s];
        if (i > n.max[0]) n.max[0] = i;
        if (s > n.max[1]) n.max[1] = s
    };
    this.setup = function() {
        this.el.css({
            overflow: "hidden",
            width: n.max[0],
            height: this.items.first().outerHeight()
        });
        this.ul.css({
            width: this.items.length * 100 + "%",
            position: "relative"
        });
        this.items.css("width", 100 / this.items.length + "%");
        if (this.opts.delay !== t) {
            this.start();
            this.el.hover(this.stop, this.start)
        }
        this.opts.keys && e(document).keydown(this.keys);
        this.opts.dots && this.dots();
        if (this.opts.fluid) {
            var r = function() {
                n.el.css("width", Math.min(Math.round(n.el.outerWidth() /
                    n.el.parent().outerWidth() *
                    100), 100) + "%")
            };
            r();
            e(window).resize(r)
        }
        if (this.opts.arrows) {
            this.el.parent().append(
                '<p class="arrows"><span class="prev">←</span><span class="next">→</span></p>'
            ).find(".arrows span").click(function() {
                e.isFunction(n[this.className]) && n[
                    this.className]()
            })
        }
        if (e.event.swipe) {
            this.el.on("swipeleft", n.prev).on("swiperight", n.next)
        }
    };
    this.move = function(t, r) { 
        if (!this.items.eq(t).length) t = 0;
        if (t < 0) t = this.items.length - 1;
        var i = this.items.eq(t);
        var s = {
            height: i.outerHeight()
        };
        var o = r ? 5 : this.opts.speed;
        if (!this.ul.is(":animated")) {
            n.el.find(".dot:eq(" + t + ")").addClass("active").siblings()
                .removeClass("active");
            this.el.animate(s, o) && this.ul.animate(e.extend({ 
                left: "-" + t + "00%" 
            }, s), o, function(i) {
                n.current = t;
                e.isFunction(n.opts.complete) && !r &&
                    n.opts.complete(n.el)
            })
        }
    };("sliderbg").fadeOut
    this.start = function() {
        n.interval = setInterval(function() {
            n.move(n.current + 1)
        }, n.opts.delay)
    };
    this.stop = function() {
        n.interval = clearInterval(n.interval);
        return n
    };
    this.keys = function(t) {
        var r = t.which;
        var i = {
            37: n.prev,
            39: n.next,
            27: n.stop
        };
        if (e.isFunction(i[r])) {
            i[r]()
        }
    };
    this.next = function() {
        return n.stop().move(n.current + 1)
    };
    this.prev = function() {
        return n.stop().move(n.current - 1)
    };
    this.dots = function() {
        var t = '<ol class="dots">';
        e.each(this.items, function(e) {
            t += '<li class="dot' + (e < 1 ? " active" :
                "") + '">' + (e + 1) + "</li>"
        });
        t += "</ol>";
        this.el.addClass("has-dots").append(t).find(".dot").click(
            function() {
                n.move(e(this).index())
            })
    }
};
e.fn.unslider = function(t) {
    var r = this.length;
    return this.each(function(i) {
        var s = e(this);
        var u = (new n).init(s, t);
        s.data("unslider" + (r > 1 ? "-" + (i + 1) : ""), u)
    })
}})(window.jQuery, false)
```

Comment: using jquery..? what about fadeIn() and fadeOut()?

Answer (score 1):

Look this fork, add the fade opt: https://github.com/jeremymlane/unslider

Comment: It would be better to copy the small section of the relevant code in your answer to give an explanation, rather than just leave a link (you can edit your answer to do so).